# Read a textfile in assets containing åäö

Tags: android, utf-8, inputstream, assets

I am having some problems reading text from a file in my assets folder. 
Its doesn't want to show åäö at all, I have used this code that I have found in different StackOverflow posts, but it won't work. I only get "?" instead
Here is the code:

```java
public void loadQuestions() throws IOException {
    atStart = false;

    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("questions.txt"), "UTF-8");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader); 
    String line = br.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        Log.d("TAG", line);
        questions.add(line);
        line = br.readLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: How can you tell you're getting ?'s? Perhaps the problem is with displaying the characters, not reading them.

Comment: Im displaying them in LogCat and in a textview and it is the same. I get "?" on every åäö.

Comment: Look at the line you read and check the *binary* value of these characters to make sure it's indeed an input problem.

Comment: I found the problem, when I save my textfile I have to save it with an enconding of UTF-8 instead of ANSI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem myself. 
When I save my textfile I have to save it with an encoding of UTF-8 and not with ANSI.

Answer (score 0):

use ISO-8859-15 as given below: It works:

```
InputStreamReader reader = new 
InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("questions.txt"), "ISO-8859-15");
```